# "The Hypercube algorithm is so ..." or "Hypercube algorithm is so..."?

Tags: articles, names, mathematics

I have an algorithm inspired by mathematical concept called hypercube. I use *Hypercube algorithm* as a name. Now when I write about it, do I need *"the"* article in front of the name *"Hypercube algorithm"*? I have similar situation where I call a technique with the name *"Most Monomial"* where I do not use *"the"* article because it is a name such as Donald Duck. Is *"the"* article needed in front of the *"Hypercube algorithm"* or not?

Comment: If the name is "Hypercube," then no "the" **and** no "algorithm."  This can vary regionally.  For example, in New England we go from Route 4 to I-95, but in California they drive "the 8" .

Comment: @CarlWitthoft *"the Hypercube algorithm"* requires *"the"* while *"Hypercube"* does not require *"the"*?

Comment: Yep, exactly.  One is the object ("Hypercube");the other is the contents of the object ("the Hypercube algorithm").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posting comments as answer:

If the name is "Hypercube," then no "the" and no "algorithm." One is the object ("Hypercube");the other is the contents of the object ("the Hypercube algorithm").

This can vary regionally so far as colloquial speech goes. For example, in New England we go from Route 4 to I-95, but in California they drive "the 8" .